# Использование перегрузки оператора

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня возникла такая проблема, есть класс `Place`, он главный, и от него наследуются три класса, дело в том, что в классе `Place` нет перегруженного оператора `>>`, но он есть в остальных трех, но когда в main я создаю массив указателей типа `Place`, а потом создаю в том же массиве объекты дочерних классов, то мне пишет, что у класса `Place` нет перегруженного оператора `>>`.

```
Place * tickets[2];
tickets[0] = new Parter[count_of_tickets[0]];
tickets[1] = new Balcon[count_of_tickets[1]];
tickets[2] = new Loza[count_of_tickets[2]];
```

> Ошибка    1   error C2679: бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Place" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Объясните, чего я не понимаю.

Comment: в с++ нет утиной типизации...

Comment: 1) Тут мало кода, ошибка которую ты привел к коду не имеет отношения. 2) Ты создал массив Place на ДВА указателя и пытаешься туда сохранить 3 элемента

Comment: Вы что-то выдумывате. В приведенном вами коде нет никакого использования оператора `>>` и ошибки такой соответственно быть не может.

Comment: вобще мало кода, и непонятно как этот как код свзан с проблемой которую вы описали.

Comment: virtual operator >> в базовом классе надобы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы наверное имели ввиду такое

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// допустим так
class B {
    std::string s;
    bool b;
public:
    B() : s("yes"), b(true) {}
};
class D : public B {
    char c;
public:
    char get() const { return c; }
    friend
    std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is,  D& d)
    {
        is >> d.c;
        return is;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    B* p = new D;
    //std::cin >> *p; // ошибка конечно постольку поскольку p указывает на 
    //начало обьекта D, который построен на блоке string и bool класса B

    D* pd = static_cast<D*>(p);
    std::cin >> *pd;     // правильно
    std::cout << pd->get(); // получите то что ввели

    return 0;
}
```

В этом примере как вводить  *P компилятор не может знать
Я наверное не очень хорошо обьяснил, но надеюсь вы меня поймете